# Iframe com Flash sobre div com z-index: 9999

Tags: css, iframe, z-index, flash

Alguns componentes do meu chat em Flash ficam acima da `div` do cabeçalho. Conforme você rola a tela, esses componentes somem e reaparecem. Segue a imagem:

[image: captura]

Não tenho acesso ao Flash, esse é o problema, segue o código de inclusão do Flash:

```
          <!-- BATE-PAPO -->
          <section id="batepapo">
          <h2>Bate-Papo</h2>
          <p><iframe src="http://exemplo.org" width="100%" height="500"></iframe></p>
          </section>
          <!-- FIM BATE-PAPO -->
```

Comment: Bom dia, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Peço que por favor elabore um pouco mais sua pergunta, ou ela pode ser sinalizada como de baixa qualidade. As imagens, você pode incluir direto no post e é costumeiro incluir um pouco do seu código para que quem te ajuda tenha de onde partir. Boa sorte!

Comment: Sou iniciante, obrigado pela dica e obrigado pelas boas vindas!

Comment: @LucasSaliésBrum você verificou se tanto o iframe quanto o cabeçalho tem z-index? Em quais navegadores está tendo o problema?

Comment: @LucasSaliésBrum não ligado à pergunta, mas só pra você saber, tem uns clientes de IRC em JS/Ajax/PHP na web, acho que eliminar o flash vai ajudar seu site a ser usado em vários dispositivos móveis. Eis uma lista: http://www.vedetta.com/ajax-irc-clients-list

Comment: @Bacco o problema ocorre apenas no CrunchBang(um derivado do Debian) usando o Google Chrome, no Windows usando qualquer browser, o problema não ocorre(não que eu lembre). Obrigado pela ajuda, vou levar em consideração implementar outro tipo de chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo e não tem nada a ver com `z-index`, é só adicionar o seguinte à tag `<param>`: `wmode="transparent"`.

Então vai ficar assim, por exemplo:

```
<object width="330" height="290" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/KEkR1ox_K10?version=3&amp;f=user_uploads&amp;app=youtube_gdata&amp;rel=1&amp;border=0&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=0" style="visibility: visible;">
   <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

Após adicionar a propriedade `wmode` com o valor `transparent`, ele irá começar a respeitar o `z-index` do CSS.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Ajudou sim, obrigado e desculpe a demora.